# Five people have applied for three different positions in a store. In how many ways can the positions be filled?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

> Five people have applied for three different positions in a store. If each person is qualified for each position, in how many ways can the positions be filled?

Can someone tell me if I have to use permutations $\mathrm P(5, 3)$ or combinations $\mathrm C(5, 3)$ and why?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4):

The normal way is to see that since the positions are distinct, *order matters*, and thus it is a permutation in which there are $5\cdot4\cdot3$ ways to successively fill the $3$ distinct posts.

Another way to look at it is :

Suppose you *choose* $3$ people, in $\binom53$ ways.

You still have to *allot* them their distinctive positions in $3!$ ways,

and note that $\binom53\cdot 3!$ is precisely the same as $^5P_3$

Either way, you will see clearly that you need to use permutations.

Answer (score 4):

Well, consider the positions available. There are three. They *literally* told you that they are different. So consider positions one two and three.

You have five candidates. You fill the first position and there are 5 ways to do it.

Then you consider the second position. You already hired one person, so there are 4 people left. Hence, there are four ways to fill position two.

Lastly, there are 3 ways to fill spot three.

Hence, there are $5\cdot 4\cdot 3$ ways to fill the positions.

Secretly, we used permutations. There are are 3 positions that are *different* and hence "the order matters". There are five candidates. Hence ${_5\mathsf P}_3$.

Answer (score 3):

Label the positions are $P1, P2$ and $P3$. Remember they're different, so that could be, say, operations manager, human resources, and logistics.

Now, if you use combinations, the order in which you obtain a result does not matter. So if $A, B, C, D$ and $E$ applied (say, Alice, Bob, Carol, David and Edward), and you got $ABC$ or $CAB$ that would be the same.

However, here order does matter. When you get a permutation, assign the first person to the first job, the second person to second job, and the third person to third job.

So, for our previous example, $ABC$ would correspond to Alice getting operations manager, Bob getting human resources and Carol getting logistics. This is different than $CAB$, which amounts to Carol getting operations manager, Alice getting human resources and Bob getting logistics.

The gist of it is that, since order matters, permutations is the way to go.